# AJAX call killing CodeIgnite Session. WHy?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am using CodeIgniter 2.x . for authentication i am using flexi auth ( http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/ ). I am facing a terrible problem. On a simple ajax request i am losing session.

**Controller :**

```
$this->auth = new stdClass;

        // Load 'standard' flexi auth library by default.
        $this->load->library('flexi_auth'); 

        // Check user is logged in as an admin.
        // For security, admin users should always sign in via Password rather than 'Remember me'.
        if (! $this->flexi_auth->is_logged_in_via_password()) 
        {
            // Set a custom error message.
            $this->flexi_auth->set_error_message('You must login as an admin to access this area.', TRUE);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->flexi_auth->get_messages());
            redirect('auth');
        }
```

**Controller Function**

```
public function checkItemCode(){

        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            //die('sdasda');
            $getResult = $this->items_model->checkCodeAvailablity();
                if($getResult == false){
                    echo '<span style="color:#f00; margin-left:10px;">This code has been used for another item. Kindly use any other code. </span>';
                }else{
            //echo '<span style="color:#f00">You can use this code!!!</span>';
                }
        } // if
    } // checkItemCode
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// make loader hidden in start
    $('#Loading').hide();    

    $('#code').blur(function(){
        $('#Loading').show();
        $.post("<?php echo base_url()?>items/checkItemCode", {
            code: $('#code').val()
        }, function(response){

            $('#Loading').hide();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('Loading', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        });
        return false;
        });

});
function finishAjax(id, response){
  $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
  $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```

I have done all possible options available on net like sess_update function, MY_Session lib etc etc. but no luck.

Kindly help me out.

Best Regards.

Comment: can you please show me the code of `checkCodeAvailablity()` in `items_model`